# Loading modal popup window in asp.net mvc using HTML action link button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I am new to MVC. I am trying to generate a modal popup using HTML link button.
Below is the code I have tried so far. I am doubtful about the way I am passing the parameter values in side the `@class` and `@style` properties.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Html.ActionLink(itemAction.NextStatusDescription, "OpenBugDescription", new
{
    headerRecId = item.HeaderRecID,
    detailRecId = item.DetailRecID,
    loginId = Convert.ToString(Session["LoginID"]),
    newStatusID = itemAction.NextStatusID,
    IsReqNewSession = itemAction.IsReqNewSession,
    IsReqMail = itemAction.IsReqMail,
    emailGroupCode = itemAction.EmailGroupCode,
    @class = "data-backdrop:static; data-keyboard:false; data-target:#modal-container",
    @style = "font-size:small; data-toggle:modal"
}, new { @id = "(" + itemAction.NextStatusID + ")" })
```

Comment: The 3rd parameter is for passing values to the controller method. You need to html attributes (your `class` and `style` attributes) in the 4th parameter

Comment: You're using this overload of `ActionLink` method => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29. The third parameter used to set route values, and the fourth for HTML attributes.

Comment: @Stephen, can u please provide me an example?

Comment: An example of what? And its not clear what your asking. You mention a modal pop-up but you have not shown any code relating to that - just the code to generate a link which makes a redirect

Comment: The code part triggering modal popup is still missing. Please add further details which modal you want to show (see [mcve]).